# How to apply LabelEncoder for a specific column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, label-encoding

I have a dataset loaded by dataframe where the class label needs to be encoded using `LabelEncoder` from scikit-learn. The column `label` is the class label column which has the following classes:

```
[‘Standing’, ‘Walking’, ‘Running’, ‘null’]
```

To perform label encoding, I tried the following but it does not work. How can I fix it?

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', sep=',') 
df.apply(preprocessing.LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df['label']))
```

Comment: If you just run `preprocessing.LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df['label'])` on its own, outside of `apply()`, do you get the encoded labels?

Comment: Yes you are right, the error disappears but I don't see encoding! The classes are not transformed. That's why I use `apply()` so that the transformation applied in the dataframe

Comment: `apply()` accepts a function, which it will apply to the each point. Here you are sending the transformed data to `apply()`, not a function and hence the error.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can try as following:

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df['label'] = le.fit_transform(df.label.values)
```

Or following would work too:

```
df['label'] = le.fit_transform(df['label'])
```

It will replace original `label` values in dataframe with encoded labels.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think there is an error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'label'`. I am using Python 3.6

Comment: Is  `label` not the column in `dataframe`? or did it work?

Comment: The column `label` is the class label containing one of these values `[‘Standing’, ‘Walking’, ‘Running’, ‘null’]`

Comment: YES! `df['label'] = le.fit_transform(df['label'])` works! Thank you very much

Comment: `df['label'] = le.fit_transform(df['label'])` worked perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
df.col_name= le.fit_transform(df.col_name.values)
```

where col_name = the feature that you want to label encode

Comment: even better it would be `df.col_name.values`

Answer (score 2):

```
 from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
 le = LabelEncoder()
 X[:, 2] = le.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
```

this could be helpful if you want to change the particular column in your CSV data